# How to open a Outlook mail item in a composing state?

Tags: c#, outlook

How to open a `MailItem` using Outlook Interop dll.

This is the code I am using:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem mailItm = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem)app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
mailItm.To = "xxx@xxx.com";
mailItm.CC = "yyy@yyy.com";
mailItm.Subject = "Some Subject";
```

`mailItem.Send()` is used to send a mail. But I want to open a mail item in a composed state. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have to [`Display`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.display(v=office.15).aspx) the item:

```
mailItem.Display(false);
```

(the `false` here indicates that the `Inspector` shouldn't be modal)